# DynamoDB Time to Live (TTL) not working, despite it is active

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

UPDATE: Ok, it "kind works", it took more than ~10 minutes to call the lambda. For anyone who is reading this question I do not recommend using this feature (TTL & Stream), it is so broken, they say that it may take 48 hours in big tables, but my table has a single element.

---

It seems like the Time to Live (TTL) feature of DynamoDB is not working. Even in a table with only one item, I've been waiting for hours, but the item still remains in the database even after it should have expired.

This is my CloudFormation template. I basically copied it from the official documentation.

```
DynamoDBTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      # - AttributeName: ttl
      #   AttributeType: N
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
      # - AttributeName: ttl
      #   KeyType: RANGE
    TimeToLiveSpecification:
      AttributeName: ttl
      Enabled: true
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
```

No matter the TTL value, whether it's set in the past or the future, the document is never deleted. I've checked multiple times, and the TTL option is active.

I also use a stream for a Lambda, and the "REMOVE" events only come through if I manually delete, which indicates that the stream is functioning.

Images as reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB TTL does not delete items immediately when the expiration date expires. It can in some cases take several days, whereas you have only been waiting for hours.

> TTL typically deletes expired items within a few days. Depending on the size and activity level of a table, the actual delete operation of an expired item can vary. Because TTL is meant to be a background process, the nature of the capacity used to expire and delete items via TTL is variable (but free of charge).

If you need more strict deletion, you may have to create your own implementation of the feature.

Comment: That is not great, it was told to me the opposite, and in very rare cases it may take 48 hours.

Comment: By the way, the table as a single item!

Comment: @Rodrigo what source told you the opposite?

Comment: @jarmod, I won't be able to find it now, it was during my research on DDB, but basically it explained that in AWS there's a service that runs every 250ms, collecting documents that need to be removed due to TTL expiration, and then another service that runs at a similarly low frequency, removing them. It mentioned that ONLY in large tables, it might take up to 48 hours. I found it intriguing and thought it could be useful, but taking days for a table with just one item? That's ridiculous. I'll go back to Redis.

Comment: In fact, even Amazon doesn't recommend it for hard real-time applications, but they do endorse this approach for scenarios like sending a notification or an email.

Comment: It's not designed for the use case that you seem to have but it's extremely valuable for certain use cases (large tables, lots of items, time series data that loses relevance over time and that would be costly/onerous to identify and purge without this feature).

Comment: That's a boomer. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Consider using EventBridge Schedulers, using EB can delete your items, or send you an event within 1 minute of expiry. I will have a blog highlighting this use-case within the next couple of weeks.

Comment: My current implementation is pooling on Redis using zset, it works very well. I thought DDB could be better alternative. I'll take a look on EventBridge Schedulers, because I have to post pone the events, and the TTL event maybe a good fit. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but next time research the problem more. TTL doesn't work. I have a table that never deleted single item in the last 3 month. Although all the items are already expired.

Comment: TTL works, I suggest double checking your TTL values and ensure they are correctly defined.